# Combining FOR and CELLS to Select Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, can FOR and CELLS be combined in selecting multiple cells? For example,

```
sub diag()
range("a1,b2,c3").select
end sub
```

This selects the first three cells diagonally. Can CELLS with FOR alter RANGE here? For example,

```
sub diag()
for i = 1 to 3
cells(i, i).select
next i
end sub
```

I tried this but it just selected A1, B2, and C3 sequentially. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to use `Union` in that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it thanks to `Application.Union` function.
The code below will select the cells A1, B2, ... J10

```vb
Public Sub GroupRange()
'Define range
Dim mainRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    If mainRange Is Nothing Then
        ' Range initialization with the 1st cell
        Set mainRange = Cells(i, i)
    Else
        ' Add a new cell to the range
        Set mainRange = Application.Union(mainRange, Cells(i, i))
    End If
Next i
' Select the final range
mainRange.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try something like this:**

```
Sub diag()

Dim mysel As Range
For i = 1 To 3
    If mysel Is Nothing Then
    Set mysel = Cells(i, i)
    Else: Set mysel = Union(mysel, Cells(i, i))
    End If
Next i

mysel.Select

End Sub
```